# MediaMetadataRetriever returns null on S3

Tags: android

I have the problem that MediaMetadataRetriever always returns null for the title, but only on stock S3. It's working with CyanogenMod on S3 but not with Samsungs stock rom. Also, on my OnePlus is everything working fine.

The Code is very simple:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
String titlename = fields[count].getName();
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + titlename);
mmr.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, uri);
final String name = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

[...]

tv.setText(name + " ");
```

The TextView will show null on Samsung stock ROM, but not on other ROMs.
This is a bit strange, does someone here have an idea? If not, I'll try a third-party library for ID3 tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the same issue on ICS (On Galaxy SII and Galaxy Tab II both running ICS 4.0.3). This seems to impact only mp3.

I guess one of the solutions would be to use an external library but I also prefer to use what android offers rather then external libraries.

I have tried two solutions:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmdr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmdr.setDataSource(path);
String title = mmdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

And

```
File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream inputStream;
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
mmdr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmdr.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
inputStream.close();
String title = mmdr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

But the problem persists:
`MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE)` always retuns null.

A solution that I thought of apart from using an external library would be to query the MediaStore on the file's path:

```
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE},
                            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?",
                            new String[] { path }, null);

String title;
if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst())
 title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE))
}
```

If the MediaScanner scanned it (it should have), the info should be there. This should also work for API levels before 10.

Basically, what to do is the following: If SDK version is < 10 or the file's extension is mp3 and SDK version is 15, I query the MediaStore, otherwise I use MediaMetaDataRetriever.

Also you can try this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
    mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(audio.url, new HashMap<String, String>());
} else {
    mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(audio.url);
}
```

This is what I have tried so far to solve the issue. But I can't guarantee if it is going to work for you.

Hope I helped.

**EDIT:**  You need to pass path or file descriptor as an argument to setDataSource. Try this code:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.music);
    if (afd != null) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Actually, the Android version is 4.4.2, so it shouldn't be an API version problem, but I'll try it again after converting the files to another format (I only need it for files in my raw folder). I'll report if it worked later.

Comment: @Zazama , I am really interested to know if it is going to work for you.

Comment: I realised that converting the files to another format, it will erase my ID3 tags :/ So I looked at your other solution but didn't really get so far (I'm a beginner in android development). "mmr.setDataSource(audio.url, new HashMap<String, String>());". I don't get this to work. Android studio says the "audio.url" has to be a string, and I tried to get it working with uri.toString() but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how I can get this to work with the uri that I have from above?

Comment: Well, the problem with this is, that it's hardcoded (R.raw.music). I don't know which files are in the raw folder at first, so I get all in an Array: "final Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();". That's why i used a String with uri. Do you know a solution where I don't have to hardcore it? :/ I'm sorry if I annoy you x)

Comment: Ok, I got it to work now, I need to wait for my friend to test it, i'll report when I checked it! For now, thanks for every help that you've offered!

Comment: It's still not working with the file descriptor, I think I need to use a 3rd-party library. Thanks for the help!